# What does the Prolog colon operator mean?

Tags: prolog

I found another post that discussed the colon, but the expression doesn't look quite the same.
I see this X variable can be passed as an argument, curious what it does?

> > X = x:2

Comment: it's just a binary expression, without context in Prolog expressions are meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

Without modules, : is an infix function symbol. You can try this out by executing

```
?- x:2 =.. X.
X = [:, x, 2].
```

at the swi prompt.

Some explanation for the =.. operator: it is a relation where the left hand side is an arbitrary term "symbol(argument1, argument2,...)" and the right hand side is a list "[symbol, argument1, argument2, ...]".

hope it helps!